# Lua - generate a random hash id from a string array

Tags: arrays, hash, lua, lua-table

I need to generate a unique int id from a string array. The id should be generated the same, for the same set of strings.

In java, I do by calling `Objects.hash(str_array)` on the sorted string array. Is there something similar in lua?

Comment: Hashes aren't unique. If you've been assuming they are, you're going to be in for a nasty surprise someday.

Comment: no there isn't. you'll have to implement that yourself or find existing code/libraries. Lua has a great reference manual btw

Comment: What are you going to do with the id?